# Exception handling with a do-while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, exception, do-while

The algorithm should take in 3 integers to an ArrayList. If the input is not an integer, then there should be a prompt. When I execute my code the `catch` clause is executed, but the program runs into a infinite loop. Could someone guide me into the right direction, I appreciate the help. :-D

```
package chapter_08;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntegerList {
    static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 1;
        int inputNum;

        do {
            System.out.print("Type " + counter + " integer: " );
            try {
                inputNum = input.nextInt();
                numbers.add(inputNum);
                counter += 1;
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                System.out.println("invalid number");
            }
        } while (!(numbers.size() == 3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when the next int is read using `nextInt()` and it fails, the `Scanner` still contains the typed contents. Then, when re-entering the do-while loop, `input.nextInt()` tries to parse it again with the same contents.

You need to 'flush' the `Scanner` contents with `nextLine()`:

```
catch (Exception exc) {
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("invalid number");
}
```

---

**Notes:**

- You can remove the `counter` variable, because you're not using it. Otherwise, you could replace `counter += 1` by `counter++`.
- You can replace `while (!(numbers.size() == 3))` with `while (numbers.size() != 3)`, or even better: `while (numbers.size() < 3)`.
- When catching exceptions, you should be as specific as possible, unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise. `Exception` should be replaced by `InputMismatchException` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If `inputNum = input.nextInt();` cannot be fit into an int and a `InputMismatchException` is raised, the input of the `Scanner` is not consumed.

So after the catch, it loops and it goes again here :

```
inputNum = input.nextInt();
```

with exactly the same content in the input.

So you should execute   `input.nextLine();` in the catch statement to discard the current input and allow a new input from the user.
Besides it makes more sense to catch `InputMismatchException` rather than `Exception` as other exception with no relation with a mismatch could occur and it would not be useful to display to the user `"invalid number "` if it is not the issue :

```
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("invalid number ");
        input.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to use a `break;` in your `catch(){}` like so :

```
try {
    inputNum = input.nextInt();
    numbers.add(inputNum);
    counter += 1;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("invalid number ");
    break;
}
```

So if one input is not correct break your loop.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
inputNum = input.nextInt();
```

to

```
String inputText=input.next();
inputNum = Integer.valueOf(inputText);
```

it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the scanner to the next line. Add this line of code below the error message in the catch section.

```
input.nextLine();
```