# Try-Catch does not rerun when there is code after the try-catch block

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to run multiple try-catch blocks in a do-while loop to help catch errors such as InputMissMatch for integer and double inputs , however , I still need to be able to input strings in the same do-while loop from the console interface.

Is it possible to get the try-catch blocks to rerun after catching an exception,  instead of moving onto the next line of code and if so, how?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EmployeeBenefits {

    Map <Integer, CaptureDetails> map = new HashMap<> ();

    int number;
    String name;
    String surname;
    double grossSalary;

    int employeeNumber = 1;
    int numberOfEmployees = 0;

    public void captureDetails() {

        boolean codeIsRunning = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        do {

            inputNumberOfEmployees ();

            if (numberOfEmployees != 0) {

                for (int enterDetails = 0; enterDetails < numberOfEmployees; enterDetails++) {

                    inputEmployeeNumber ();
                    inputEmployeeNames ();
                    inputGrossSalary ();

                    map.put(employeeNumber, new CaptureDetails (number, name, surname, grossSalary));
                    employeeNumber++;
                }
            }

            codeIsRunning = false;

        } while (codeIsRunning); // end of do-while loop

    } //  end of captureDetails () method

    public void inputNumberOfEmployees () {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        try {

            System.out.print ("Enter the number of employees to input: ");
            numberOfEmployees = input.nextInt();

        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            System.out.println ("\nYou must enter an integer value. Please try agin\n");
            input.nextLine();
        }

    } // end of inputNumberOfEmployees()

    public void inputEmployeeNumber () {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        try {

            System.out.print ("Enter Number: ");
            number = input.nextInt();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            System.out.println("\nYou must enter an integer value. Please try agin\n");
            input.nextLine ();

        }

    } // end of inputEmployeeNumber()

    public void inputGrossSalary () {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        try {
            System.out.print ("Enter Gross Salary: ");
            grossSalary = input.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println ("\nEnter employees salary. Please try agin\n");
            input.nextLine ();
        }

    } // inputGrossSalary ()

    public void inputEmployeeNames () {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter Name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print ("Enter Surname: ");
        surname = input.nextLine();

    } // end of inputEmployeeNames

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmployeeBenefits eb = new EmployeeBenefits ();

        boolean programIsRunning = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        while (programIsRunning) {

            System.out.println ("1. Enter Employee details");
            System.out.println ("2. Set New Salary");
            System.out.println ("3. Print Employee Details");
            System.out.println ("4. Exit");

            switch (input.nextInt()) {

                case 1:
                    eb.captureDetails ();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    programIsRunning = false;
                    break;

                default :
                    System.out.println ("Enter a value between from 1 to 4\n");

            } // end of switch-case (input.nextInt())

        } // end of while (programIsRunning) loop  

    } // end of main method

} // end of EmployeeBenefits class


class CaptureDetails {

    int number;
    String name, surname;
    double grossSalary;

    public CaptureDetails (int number, String name, String surname, double grossSalary) {

        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.grossSalary = grossSalary;

    }

} // end of CaptureDetails class
```

Comment: You can put a try-catch in the loop.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Is it possible to get the try-catch blocks to rerun after catching an exception,  instead of moving onto the next line of code and if so, how?

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282638/exception-handling-with-a-do-while-loop-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can prompt for input in a loop.  The problem is... You're not using a loop:

```
public void inputNumberOfEmployees () {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    try {
        System.out.print ("Enter the number of employees to input: ");
        numberOfEmployees = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println ("\nYou must enter an integer value. Please try agin\n");
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

If you want to perform this logic in a loop, then wrap it in a loop.  In this case the terminating condition would be whether or not the input was successful.  So you can track that with a simple boolean flag.  Perhaps something like this:

```
public void inputNumberOfEmployees () {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    boolean isInvalid = true;
    while (isInvalid) {

        try {
            System.out.print ("Enter the number of employees to input: ");
            numberOfEmployees = input.nextInt();

            isInvalid = false;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println ("\nYou must enter an integer value.\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Kind Person :)

Answer (score 1):

You can recall your method from the catch statement or you can add a while loop that checks for valid input.

```
public void inputNumberOfEmployees () {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    try {

        System.out.print ("Enter the number of employees to input: ");
        numberOfEmployees = input.nextInt();

    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {

        System.out.println ("\nYou must enter an integer value. Please try agin\n");
        inputNumberOfEmployees(); // This is the Change
    }

} // end of inputNumberOfEmployees()
```

Comment: This works, although you'd eventually get a stack overflow if they entered the wrong input too many times.

Comment: Recursion isn't a particularly intuitive replacement for a simple loop.

Comment: Thank You Kind Person :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
public void inputEmployeeNumber () {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid)
    {
        try {

            System.out.print ("Enter Number: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            isValid = true;

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            System.out.println("\nYou must enter an integer value. Please try agin\n");
            input.nextLine ();

        }
    }

} // end of inputEmployeeNumber()
```

Comment: Thank You Kind Person :)

Answer (score -2):

Try a **continue** *label* statement inside **catch block** to **try block** . It will repeatedly try to get the input untill no exception is caught