# Do-while in try catch

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, do-while

I get infinite loop in catch...It is supposed to ask user to enter again.
Please help

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter number : ");
                num = input.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Enter number only !!!");
            }
        } while (num != 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: how can a user with this much reputation ask a question so carelessly.

Comment: @FarhanQasim And doesn't know how to delete his own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to leave do-while loop you need to type number `5`

Comment: I want to allow user enter number again if application failed

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this at first. You need to call `input.next();` in the catch clause.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are comparing a NON-Number with a number in while(num!=5). Due to Exception the another input is not taken from the user and the previous NON-Number input is saved into 'num' variable and so infinite times Exception occurs and executes catch(){}.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you're trying to do. What does your do-while thing suppose to mean? Anyway, if you want to check whether the number entered by the user is NUMERIC and not Non-Numeric, you should do

```
System.out.print("Enter Number ");  
Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in);  

try {   
String str = input.next();  
int x=  Integer.parseInt(str);         

}  
catch(Exception e) {  
 System.out.print("Type a Number, Not String");               
}
```

Comment: Also, you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282638/exception-handling-with-a-do-while-loop-in-java for exception handling in do-while loop

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you do `num = input.nextInt();` for a non-numeric input like `a`, the buffer in the scanner `a` is still present as it is not read and it will be available for the next scan which you are invoking with `do-while`. So, there goes your infinite loop.

Solve it by clearing the input buffer with `input.nextLine` in your catch.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Enter number only !!!");
    input.nextLine();
}
```

see the reference made by @Ojasvi

Answer (score 0):

you are not incrementing **num** so it will remain **0** forever and there will be infinte loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

as you are missed to place  `num = input.nextInt();` into your catch block.
one more thing it remains into the looped untill you give the input number as 5.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter number : ");
                num = input.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Enter number only !!!");
                num = input.nextInt();
            }
        } while (num != 5);
    }

}
```